# How to know the details of WHO sharing my FB posts with Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can see the details of likes and comments(who and which ID likes or comments my posts) with Graph API of Facebook For Developers, And I could also see the share counts by typing "me?fields=posts{shares}", but it's just the counts. How can I see details of "who" sharing my FB posts?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/sharedposts

Comment: be aware that you are not allowed to incentivize sharing. you can´t reward users in any way for it, and you can´t make it a requirement for a promotion. just saying, because people usually want to know who shared something for that case.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot ！